# Symfony Forms manual submission of both GET and POST requests

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is there any way to get merged data from Request class? Because currently we are submitting forms manually for API controller that accepts both POST and GET queries (this is not an REST API because of legacy project).

```
$data = array_merge($request->query->all(), $request->request->all());
$form->submit($data);
```

Is there any way to write something cleaner instead of code below?

```
$data = array_merge($request->query->all(), $request->request->all());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is **not possible**. *(Maybe I'm wrong)*

If you look at the [source code of Request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php), you can see that when Symfony create the request, Symfony put the global variable `$_GET` in `$this->query` and `$_POST` in `$this->request`.
There is no Symfony variable that takes both.

If you need it in only one place, I think what you have done is fine.

If not, create a service that will or another solution that factors this code.

Another solution is to use the global variable `$_REQUEST`, because Symfony makes the [merge](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L542), but it depends on your php configuration (`request_order` parameter of your `php.ini`). 
But I do not think using [Superglobals](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) variables with Symfony is a good idea ... (Besides symfony [overwrites](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L512) them)

Comment: If you need to do it at multiple places, i would suggest to create an Annotation.

Comment: @Terenoth which annotation and what should it do?

Comment: @SergeySmirnov I meant a custom Annotation. Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/your-own-custom-annotations/